# Authenticating to create a new instance from AMI without hard coding secrey key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web application running on `Elastic Bean Stalk`. In the web application I have a `Java Class` that will authenticate to EC2 using the `AWS Access Key` and `AWS Secret Key` in either `system environment variables` or hard coded keys in the same `Class`.

My question is, is there a way any way to perform some operations in `EC2` without hard coding the keys or getting it from the `Environment variables`?

I read about `IAM`. I created a `IAM User` and assigned permissions to the users. The aforementioned key belongs to this user.

The reason why I don't want to hard code keys is because it's less secure and also I feel having it in `Environment variable` less secure as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about "authenticate to EC2" but you should use the [instance profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html) to access AWS services if you are running application in EC2 instance. You can refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) how to manage the credentials for Java.

Answer (score 0):

In IAM, you create a role, and assign the desired permissions for your EC2 instance.

You can then associate that role with the EC2 instance.  Any AWS aware tools, or application written using an AWS SDK, will then use that role to obtain temporary credentials to do what they need to do.

If you want to do this on your own, you will need to obtain temporary credentials as per [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-roles-calling.html).  This involves a call to the local instance metadata service:

```
GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole
```

Comment: When you say "AWS aware tools" does it mean my application too? How do I make my application aware of the IAM?